# How to change of out stock error message in magento2?

Tags: magento-2.1, out-of-stock, error-message

I need to modify out of stock error message in cart page in magento2?

In Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator.php:

```
 public function validate(Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $quoteItem Item */
        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
        if (!$quoteItem ||
            !$quoteItem->getProductId() ||
            !$quoteItem->getQuote()
        ) {
            return;
        }
        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();echo '  ' . $product->getId();
        $qty = $quoteItem->getQty();

        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item $stockItem */
        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
        if (!$stockItem instanceof StockItemInterface) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('The Product stock item is invalid. Verify the stock item and try again.'));
        }

        if (($options = $quoteItem->getQtyOptions()) && $qty > 0) {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $this->optionInitializer->initialize($option, $quoteItem, $qty);
            }
        } else {
            $this->stockItemInitializer->initialize($stockItem, $quoteItem, $qty);
        }

        if ($quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
            return;
        }

        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $stockStatus */
        $stockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $parentStockStatus */
        $parentStockStatus = false;

        /**
         * Check if product in stock. For composite products check base (parent) item stock status
         */
        if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
            $product = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct();
            $parentStockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus(
                $product->getId(),
                $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
            );
        }

        if ($stockStatus) {
            if ($stockStatus->getStockStatus() === Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
                    || $parentStockStatus && $parentStockStatus->getStockStatus() == Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
            ) {
                $quoteItem->addErrorInfo(
                    'cataloginventory',
                    Data::ERROR_QTY,
                    __('This product is out of stock.')
                );
                $quoteItem->getQuote()->addErrorInfo(
                    'stock',
                    'cataloginventory',
                    Data::ERROR_QTY,
                    __('Some of the products are out of stockss.')
                );
                return;
            } else {
                // Delete error from item and its quote, if it was set due to item out of stock
                $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Check item for options
         */
        if ($options) {
            $qty = $product->getTypeInstance()->prepareQuoteItemQty($qty, $product);
            $quoteItem->setData('qty', $qty);
            if ($stockStatus) {
                $this->checkOptionsQtyIncrements($quoteItem, $options);
            }

            // variable to keep track if we have previously encountered an error in one of the options
            $removeError = true;
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                $result = $option->getStockStateResult();
                if ($result->getHasError()) {
                    $option->setHasError(true);
                    //Setting this to false, so no error statuses are cleared
                    $removeError = false;
                    $this->addErrorInfoToQuote($result, $quoteItem, $removeError);
                }
            }
            if ($removeError) {
                $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
            }
        } else {
            if ($quoteItem->getParentItem() === null) {
                $result = $quoteItem->getStockStateResult();
                if ($result->getHasError()) {
                    $this->addErrorInfoToQuote($result, $quoteItem);
                } else {
                    $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Why way is better and correct one to change stock error message.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

change it in i18n/en_US.csv

**"This product is out of stock."** to  your modified errorMessage

if you want to add message on condition base please make after plugin:

in di.xml

```
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
            <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator">
                <plugin name="Vendor_Module_Plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\ValidatorPlugin" sortOrder="10" disabled="false"  />
            </type>
        </config>
```

in Vendor\Module\Plugin\ValidatorPlugin.php file

```
                <?php

                namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

                class ValidatorPlugin
                {

                    public function afterValidate(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator $subject, \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
                    {

                        /* @var $quoteItem Item */
                        $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
                        if (!$quoteItem ||
                            !$quoteItem->getProductId() ||
                            !$quoteItem->getQuote()
                        ) {
                            return;
                        }
                        $product = $quoteItem->getProduct();
                        $qty = $quoteItem->getQty();

                        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\Item $stockItem */
                        $stockItem = $this->stockRegistry->getStockItem($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());
                        if (!$stockItem instanceof StockItemInterface) {
                            throw new LocalizedException(__('The Product stock item is invalid. Verify the stock item and try again.'));
                        }

                        if (($options = $quoteItem->getQtyOptions()) && $qty > 0) {
                            foreach ($options as $option) {
                                $this->optionInitializer->initialize($option, $quoteItem, $qty);
                            }
                        } else {
                            $this->stockItemInitializer->initialize($stockItem, $quoteItem, $qty);
                        }

                        if ($quoteItem->getQuote()->getIsSuperMode()) {
                            return;
                        }

                        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $stockStatus */
                        $stockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId());

                        /* @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockStatusInterface $parentStockStatus */
                        $parentStockStatus = false;

                        /**
                         * Check if product in stock. For composite products check base (parent) item stock status
                         */
                        if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
                            $product = $quoteItem->getParentItem()->getProduct();
                            $parentStockStatus = $this->stockRegistry->getStockStatus(
                                $product->getId(),
                                $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId()
                            );
                        }

                        if ($stockStatus) {
                            if ($stockStatus->getStockStatus() === Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
                                    || $parentStockStatus && $parentStockStatus->getStockStatus() == Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
                            ) {
                                $quoteItem->addErrorInfo(
                                    'cataloginventory',
                                    Data::ERROR_QTY,
                                    __('This product is out of stock.')
                                );

                                //make custom condition here

                                $quoteItem->getQuote()->addErrorInfo(
                                    'stock',
                                    'cataloginventory',
                                    Data::ERROR_QTY,
                                    __('Some of the products are out of stock.')
                                );
                                return;
                            } else {
                                // Delete error from item and its quote, if it was set due to item out of stock
                                $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
                            }
                        }

                        /**
                         * Check item for options
                         */
                        if ($options) {
                            $qty = $product->getTypeInstance()->prepareQuoteItemQty($qty, $product);
                            $quoteItem->setData('qty', $qty);
                            if ($stockStatus) {
                                $this->checkOptionsQtyIncrements($quoteItem, $options);
                            }

                            // variable to keep track if we have previously encountered an error in one of the options
                            $removeError = true;
                            foreach ($options as $option) {
                                $result = $option->getStockStateResult();
                                if ($result->getHasError()) {
                                    $option->setHasError(true);
                                    //Setting this to false, so no error statuses are cleared
                                    $removeError = false;
                                    $this->addErrorInfoToQuote($result, $quoteItem, $removeError);
                                }
                            }
                            if ($removeError) {
                                $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($quoteItem->getParentItem() === null) {
                                $result = $quoteItem->getStockStateResult();
                                if ($result->getHasError()) {
                                    $this->addErrorInfoToQuote($result, $quoteItem);
                                } else {
                                    $this->_removeErrorsFromQuoteAndItem($quoteItem, Data::ERROR_QTY);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    }
```

Comment: I want to add some condition on it.

Comment: then make after plugin for it @ManoM

Comment: @ManoM i have updated my answer check

Comment: Add "Parent product is out of stock" and "child product is out of stock" based upon stock

Comment: change  if ($stockStatus->getStockStatus() === Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
                                    || $parentStockStatus && $parentStockStatus->getStockStatus() == Stock::STOCK_OUT_OF_STOCK
                            ) in above plugin

Answer (score 0):

You could rewrite the class.  Something like this. Depends on the level of change required though.

di.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator" type="Xigen\Stock\Rewrite\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator"/>
</config>
```

QuantityValidator.php

```php
namespace Xigen\Stock\Rewrite\Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item;

class QuantityValidator extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator
{
    public function validate(Observer $observer)
    {
        // changes
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify this would be within your own extension e.g. https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/magento-2-modules/

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to achieve this requirement.

The easiest one would be to simply create a translation. A localized exception takes as input a Phrase parameter that can be translated.

Simply add the string "The Product stock item is invalid. Verify the stock item and try again." and you're good to go.

The other option that I thought of is an around plugin on the validate method.
I tried to do some kind of blind implementation without a real test (it should work, but I'm not sure :) )

**app/code/JBrada/ModuleName/Plugin/Quote/Item/QuantityValidator ↓**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace JBrada\ModuleName\Plugin\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator;

use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class ChangeMessagePlugin
{
    public function aroundValidate(QuantityValidator $subject, callable $proceed, Observer $observer): void
    {
        try {
            $proceed($observer);
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $phrase = __('The Product stock item is invalid. Verify the stock item and try again.');
            if ($e->getRawMessage() === $phrase->getText()) {
                throw new LocalizedException(__('This is my custom Message!'))
            }
            
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

**app/code/JBrada/MyModule/di.xml ↓**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator">
        <plugin name="jbrada_quot_item_quantityvalidator_change_message"
                type="JBrada\ModuleName\Plugin\Quote\Item\QuantityValidator\ChangeMessagePlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```